# How to increase the size of checkbox mean height and width?

Tags: jquery, css

can you please tell me how to increase the size of checkbox mean height and width.

I used like that  But still size is not increase same size..

```
<input name="" type="checkbox" value="" class="big">

 input.big {
        height: 15em;
        width: 15em;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of a lot of similar questions asked here. I suggest you to surf stackoverflow and you will get the answer.

Comment: [Cross browser checkbox generator](http://csscheckbox.com/)

Comment: can you please some example on fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these checkboxes are not customizable.you have to use some external approach

i think this may hepl u [customizable checkbox and radio button](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css)

```
<p>
    <input type="radio" value="male" id="male" name="gender" />
    <label for="male">Male</label>
</p>
```

css:

```
p:not(#foo) > input + label {
    background: url(gr_custom-inputs.png) 0 -1px no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 0 0 0 18px;
}
```

See [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/34J3j/197/)

Comment: can you give one example on fiddle

Comment: @user2075328 added jsfiddle

Answer (score 4):

Do like this:

```
input[type=checkbox]
    {
        /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
        -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
        -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
        -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
        padding: 10px;
    }
    input.big {           
        font-size: 110%;
        display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. Please see this screen grab:
http://d.pr/i/FRuF

May be you are missing doctype tag on top:
<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: there is problem on click .if you select it os showing black checkbox